# Trying to automate facebook login and writing a post on friends timeline

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the code attached:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/")
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("***EMAIL***")
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("***PW***")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginbutton']").click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
ele = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
ele.send_keys("**FRIEND NAME**")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='js_e']/form/button/i")))
element.click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='js_9t']/img")))
element.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='js_3q9']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div").send_keys("Its Automated")
```

The code is not working and gets stuck after logging in or after searching my friend's name and sometimes not even writing my friend's name. It's different every time not able to figure out what to do. The element locators also change all of sudden. Below are the errors I'm getting:

1) `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state`

2) `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

3) `Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: Please paste the actual error output from your console. Trying to abbreviate it as you have just adds to the confusion.

Comment: try to change this     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='js_3q9']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div").send_keys("Its Automated")
 xpath to a relative xpath of text box/area where you want to write

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fb.py", line 20, in <module>
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='js_e']/form/button/i")))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

This is the error i m getting now.

Comment: The code is not able to reach till last line.I will edit that xpath and try.

Comment: How to find element with the HTML link?                                                   <div data-offset-key="282s5-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset-key="282s5-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div>  I m unable to use its css or xpath to locate element.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. The element you are trying to access via xpath is not being found on the document/page. Consequently, Selenium waits for a bit before timing out.